# .env process.env isn't working with DocuSign docusignAPI using node.js example

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, docusignapi, dotenv

I'm using the example from docusign at https://github.com/docusign/qs-02-node-send-envelope ,
and have configured the `index.js` file the ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID, USER_FULLNAME and USER_EMAIL it worked fine. But when I configure the `.env` file it doesn't work.

I did install `$ npm install` and `$ npm install dotenv`.

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=eyJ0eXMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzETtl0--w
ACCOUNT_ID=123456
USER_FULLNAME="Larry Smith"
USER_EMAIL=myemail@mail.com
```

this is the localhost answer

```
API problem

Status code 401

Error message:

{
    "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",
    "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."
}
```

with the `console.log(accessToken)` it replies `ACCESS_TOKEN`instead of `eyJ0eXMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzETtl0--w`

Need help to set up process.env with docusign or docusignapi.

Comment: Do you have `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) docs:

As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

You may turn on logging to help debug why certain keys or values are not being set as you expect.

```
require('dotenv').config({ debug: process.env.DEBUG })
```